# Comparison of variables from a string (Java)

Tags: java

Assume, I have some variable Y = 6. I have an array of variables X: 12 22 32 11 56. I need to write a program, which will match my variable Y among array variables until success or end. The matching algorithm checkes whether some variable from X is greater or equal 2Y, starting from the smallest value. Values are not ordered. All values (both X and Y) are putting through console; values in X are divided by space. Once such value in X is found, it becomes futher checking, but now it replaces Y with first succesfull X etc.

In example above. 11 - no. 12 - yes. 22 - no (related to 12). 32 - yes. 56 - no.

As a result I want to have to sum of successful matches, in this case - 2.

To get values from array I use this code:

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
String vvod = br.readLine();
String[] tok=vvod.split(" ");
for (int i=0; i<tok.length;i++) {
     int x=Integer.parseInt(tok[i]);
```

I find difficulties with matching algorithm, as once I have a success, I have to change to number I matching with. I also have problems with ordering values from the string.

P.S. Just learning how to code.

Comment: If you find a match for Y in the array what do you want with it?

Comment: If I find some variable from X that is greater or equals to 2Y, then I replace Y by that variable and continue checking the values until the end. In the end I have to output the number of successfull matches.

Comment: What is the problem in that?  Simply check if(x>2y)  is yes then replace y with x else continue in your loop.

Comment: You say you're having a problem. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
int y = 6; // replace with your starting y wherever you are generating it
int[] x = {12, 22, 32, 11, 56}; // replace with your own generated array
Arrays.sort(x); // Remember to import java.util.Arrays; at the top of your file

int matches = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    if(x[i] >= 2*y)
    {
       matches++;
       y = x[i];
    }
}
System.out.println(matches); // Print or return depending on your needs here
```

Comment: It is almost what I need, Thank you. But there are 2 problems anyway: 1) User inputs variables through console, so I use code presented above to separate it and store as String[]. I try to check if(x[i] >= 2*y), where y is int and x is String[]. That creates difficulties with moving to your part of the code. 2) Your code output is not some value, but values, represented in different strings, I only need max of then. I tried various methods, but always fail as I have different types of variables in my code int, String, String[],

Comment: In your code below `String[] tok=vvod.split(" ");` make a new array of integers of the same length like this: `int[] x = new int[tok.length]` then replace the line `int x=Integer.parseInt(tok[i]);` in your code with `x[i] =Integer.parseInt(tok[i]);` that should give you an array of integers to fit into my code. As for the return simple change the `System.out.println(matches);` to whatever you need. @Bear

Comment: Thank you, Corey. Thats helped me a lot.